# Equivalent function to input() in openCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, input

I have written a small application in which a user clicks regions of an image to label, then labels that region of the image with a string. I use openCV's `onMouseCallback()` to manage the clicks, and I read strings in using the `input()` function. However, this is a less-than-desirable solution because the user must click to the console, type the string into the console, press enter, and then click back to the image window, for each labeling string.

**Is there a function in OpenCV that would allow for inputting a string without ever clicking away from the openCV window, essentially analogous to the`input()` function?**

One could probably achieve this result by defining a series of keystroke handlers, but this would be somewhat tedious to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a fairly simple solution, but I figured I'd post it here rather than deleting my question because I couldn't find this solution elsewhere on SE or online. This doesn't currently work for special characters:

```
import string    

def keyboard_input():
    text = ""
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    while True:
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        for letter in letters:
            if key == ord(letter):
                text = text + letter
        if key == ord("\n") or key == ord("\r"): # Enter Key
            break
    return text
```